# unit testing Freemarker and Spring

Tags: unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a freemarker template and I want to write a test that checks the output for a given model input.

```
@Test
public void testProcessTemplateWithModel() throws Exception {
    final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(directoryForTemplateLoading);
    configuration.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
    final Template template = configuration.getTemplate("template.ftl");
    final Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    /* populate model */
    template.process(model, new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
}
```

Trouble is that the first line in the template is:

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
```

So I get:

```
ERROR [main] freemarker.runtime - Error reading imported file spring.ftl

Error reading imported file spring.ftl
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> import "spring.ftl" as spring [on line 1, column 1 in template.ftl]
----------
```

Setting the import on the template seems to be impossible.

Comment: did you checked the path of spring.ftl?

Comment: @Aby -- It was nearly a year ago; I don't even remember posting this question!

Comment: I realise this question was asked over a year ago - but I'm posting a response just in case someone else finds their way here looking for an answer. I've recently been dealing with the same issue and came up with practical (I think) solution: http://stuartgunter.org/unit-testing-views-spring-mvc/ I also use FreeMarker, but this approach would work equally well with any other view technology that does not require a servlet container (so Velocity would work well too).